# What are the answers to this linguistics graduate-student entrance exam question?

Tags: linguistics

I thought this would be an interesting puzzle for some users here.  This is an exam question for university graduate students in linguistics ([source](https://max.book118.com/html/2018/0527/169031626.shtm)):

> [image]
>
> 一。填空题（每题3分，共30分）
>
> 1. 现代汉民族共同语是以_____为基础方言。
> 2. 从发音部位分，普通话的声母m属_____。
> 3. 词是最小的_____的语言单位。
> 4. 从结构关系看，“风浪、寒冷、开关”这类词是_____式。
> 5. “腐败”的反义词是_____。
> 6. “关系很密切”中的“密切”是形容词，而在“密切关系”中是_____。
> 7. 短语“木头房子”的结构关系是_____。
> 8. 句子“这件事我来办。”的主语是_____。
> 9. 由“既然……就……”链接的复句是_____关系。
> 10. 言外之意是指_____。

I don't know most of the answers myself.  My partial answers:

> I'm guessing 3 is 带有意义.  Actually, 腐败 has two antonyms, one is 新鲜 and the other is 清廉 or 廉洁 (I had to look up this second one; I encountered it a long time ago when I first met 腐败).  I'd be rather surprised if 6 is not also 形容词, but the question seems to suggest it.  I'm fairly confident the subject of 7 is 我 (not 这件事).  I think 9 is 因果关系.  And I'm not sure how to fill in the blank in 10, but it's something like 非字面的意思, non-textual meaning.

**Question**: What are the answers to this linguistics graduate-student entrance exam question?

Comment: The subject for 这件事我来办 is indeed 这件事，not 我. According to Chinese grammar, 这件事我来办 is a 主谓谓语句 in which 主谓短语 is used as 谓语. In this case, 我来办 is the predicate(谓语).

Comment: I'd suspect that the answer for "词是最小的_____的语言单位。" is "有意義" but that is not strictly correct because morphemes carry semantics, too. OTOH my guess may be wrong so now for the spoiler...

Comment: 5. 清廉 ˙8. "我"来办这件事 10. 隱喻

Comment: 6. I suspect they're going for [狀語 Adverb](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8B%80%E8%AA%9E) in so far as 關係 can be understood as a verb

Comment: Write an answer, guys! Make it a community wiki answer if you’re unsure.

Comment: #2 /m/ is a bilabial nasal 雙唇鼻音.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community Wiki answer (please edit):

> 1. 现代汉民族共同语是以[**北方话**](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%8E%B0%E4%BB%A3%E6%B1%89%E6%B0%91%E6%97%8F%E5%85%B1%E5%90%8C%E8%AF%AD/5689128)为基础方言。
> 2. 从发音部位分，普通话的声母m属[**双唇鼻音**](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8F%8C%E5%94%87%E9%BC%BB%E9%9F%B3/8513213)。
> 3. 词是最小的[**有意义的独立运用的**](https://www.zhihu.com/question/515161836)的语言单位。 (It's not 有意义 by itself; that's
>    [语素](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%AF%AD%E7%B4%A0/1321734) = "morpheme".)
> 4. 从结构关系看，“风浪、寒冷、开关”这类词是**并列**式。
> 5. “腐败”的反义词是**清廉**。 (Also possible is **新鲜** and **清明**, according to my dictionary.)
> 6. “关系很密切”中的“密切”是形容词，而在“密切关系”中是**动词**。 (The sentence implies the answer is not 形容词.)

主语、谓语、宾语、状语、补语 etc. are syntactical functions/positions. 名词、形容词、动词、副词 etc. are parts of speech.

密切关系 can be a NP, where 密切 is adj. and 关系 is a noun. ex.我们的密切关系

密切关系 can be a VP, where 密切 is vt. and 关系 is a noun. ex. 我们要密切关系，紧密联系。

Since it's implicitly asking for something other than adj., 动词 is more appropriate.

> 7. 短语“木头房子”的结构关系是**定中关系**。(定语+中心语)
> 8. 句子“这件事我来办。”的主语是“**这件事**”。  (See: [Baidu Baike 主谓谓语句](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%B8%BB%E8%B0%93%E8%B0%93%E8%AF%AD%E5%8F%A5/999375); the question is likely referring to 全句的主语, which is 这件事.)
> 9. 由“既然……就……”链接的复句是[**因果**](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/436773342391793684.html)关系。
> 10. 言外之意是指[**没有在话里明说，而是通过暗示手法表达出来的真正意思**](https://epaper.xkb.com.cn/view/1133028)。

Answer (score 0):

“腐败”的反义词是清廉。 (But 新鲜 is wrong as 新鲜 means fresh)